# Using SDL2 and xcode 4.6. I manage to create a OpenGL 3.2 core context. BUT can not use glsl 1.50

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl

I am using an example from internet that the author says it works, and it looks legit to me.

So, I downloaded SDL2 and built the framework in debug. I create a regular Opengl 2.1 app to check that SDL was built properly and I could debug it.

Then I create a OpenGL 3.2 core context I checked that the major version was 3 and the minor 2 (calling to GlGetIntegerv ).

I also used this line:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

and I double check that fixed-pipeline calls are useless now. So far, so good.

The problem is when I try to use shaders for glsl 1.50. It fails to compile, and give some error similar to (I apologize, I don't have the error in front right now): **ERROR 0:2 syntax error syntax error**

The shaders loading code looks like this:

```
char* filetobuf(char *file)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    long length;
    char *buf;

    fptr = fopen(file, "rb"); /* Open file for reading */
    if (!fptr) /* Return NULL on failure */
        return NULL;
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END); /* Seek to the end of the file */
    length = ftell(fptr); /* Find out how many bytes into the file we are */
    buf = (char*)malloc(length+1); /* Allocate a buffer for the entire length of the file and a null terminator */
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET); /* Go back to the beginning of the file */
    fread(buf, length, 1, fptr); /* Read the contents of the file in to the buffer */
    fclose(fptr); /* Close the file */
    buf[length] = 0; /* Null terminator */

    return buf; /* Return the buffer */
}
```

and the shaders:

```
vertex shader
#version 150 core
 
uniform mat4 viewMatrix, projMatrix;
 
in vec4 position;
in vec3 color;
 
out vec3 Color;
 
void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * position ;
}

fragment shader:
#version 150 core
 
in vec3 Color;
out vec4 outputF;
 
void main()
{
    outputF = vec4(Color,1.0);
}
```

If I don't use a 3.2 core context, I get "version not supported". But not now, so the error must be something else.

Any clue?

**UPDATE**
Indeed, something things to be wrong on the reading shader file, because I just created a const char * and wrote the whole shader in it and passed the reference to glShaderSource() and it works now. The funny thing, is I still don't understand what is wrong with filetobuf() (I applied Armin fix).

Comment: Can you more specific about the error, on what line does the error occur, does it disappear if you remove certain parts of the code?

Comment: I will update the case with more information as soon as I am back home and can try the fix suggested by you. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the shader for illegal(non-ascii) chars? If you copied the shader from a web page their might be some unicode characters in it (check it with printf or NSLog). If you are on a OsX System try to import the Foundations framework and use NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding

Answer (score 0):

You are using [fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) incorrectly.

Instead of

```
fread(buf, length, 1, fptr);
```

it should be

```
fread(buf, 1, length, fptr);
```

This might not be the problem, as far as i can see the your read function is void of any errors, but it is still preferable to use library functions as they were intended.

I'm not sure for the second part of your code though. Posting a more descriptive error message would help.

Comment: It is interesting to observe how certain people quickly diminish their errors by pointing out even the most trivial mistakes in others so they can feel better about themselves.

Comment: Armin: I made a mistake and deleted my wrong answer. And I point out that your answer doesn't have any substancial value either, not to feel better, but so that you can make the proper adjustments as well. BTW: I didn't downvote (your answer has no votes yet whatsoever).

Comment: Please, don't fight :) I am not able to check this fix yet until I am back home

Comment: so, as I said in the update from the post, the solution was to put the whole shader in a const char *. That proves that is something wrong with filetobuf(), but I don't understand what. Armin, your fix, even though is right, does not fixed the issue. It has to be something else.

Thanks for your help!